# conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Tags: spring, proguard

i get this error after i obfuscate my project , eventghout only my implementation class  com.company.project.f.a.a.b  is qualified by `@Component("myImpl")`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation-specified bean name
>   'myImpl' for bean class
>   [com.company.project.f.a.a.b] conflicts with existing, non-compatible
>   bean definition of same name and class [com.company.project.f.a.a.a]

i don't realy understand why spring attributes the same name for both the interface and the implementation . could it be something wrong with my Proguard config ?

Comment: I don't think that Proguard and Spring will be compatible, since Proguard renames class, attributes etc... :(

Comment: i switched to an annotation based configuration , which makes it okay for proguard to rename classes attribues etc .. i'm only struggling with this obstacles .. if i overcome it , it can definetly work.

Comment: And what's `com.company.project.f.a.a.a` ?

Comment: com.company.project.f.a.a.a is the interface implemented in com.company.project.f.a.a.b

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't any old jar in your classpath ?

Comment: i'm sure there's no old jar interfering , i think there might be something wrong with the obfuscation , maybe proguard treats annotations in a weird way .

Comment: try to decompile the obfuscated class, and check that your annotations are still there. Sorry, no better idea for the moment :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the source of the problem , Proguard merges interaces with their implementation if the optimizer is enabled.

i added

```
-dontoptimize
```

and the probleme is solved

Comment: Proguard also can rename the existing classes to same name, let say 'a'. If there are 2 classes which has @Component and if both are renamed with 'a' as part of obfuscation, then it will lead to duplicate bean issue during start up. To solve this problem, i used -keepnames class package1 -keepnames class package2. Is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 3):

What you can try is to keep `@Component` classes `as is` by telling proguard to do so through a `-keep` option.

In case if you use a proguarg maven plugin you can set this option as:

```
<plugin>
    ... ...
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ... ...
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
            ... ...
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *</option>
            ... ...
        </options>
        ... ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It'll keep `@Component` components reverse engineer and Spring friendly :)

Comment: i'm already using this  option  :   -keepattributes *Annotation*
but i'll try what you suggested , but i can tell that proguard will not change the name of every class using the annotation "Component" and this is not good cuz it'll end up keep the whole application :D since i'm extensively using spring injection and different layers .

Comment: since you were the only one who posted an answer :D i guess i'll just offer you the bounty ;) i can't reward myself anyway :)  
thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
for @Component
 <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *</option>
for @Controller
 <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller class *</option> 
for @Service
 <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Service class *</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem occurs if you have moved your classes around and it refers to old classes, even if they don't exist.

In this case, just do this :

```
mvn eclipse:clean

mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This worked well for me.